# Twitter Bot That Tweets When I Perform A Cloudflare Wrangler API Call with Typescript But I Get "{unknown error}"

Tags: typescript, webpack, twitter, twitter-oauth, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to build a Twitter bot in with node and typescript. I have a Twitter Dev account and API OAuth credentials set up. I am also using cloudflare wrangler. The project's purpose is simply to do an API request to Tweet. I set up a local cloudflare wrangler typescript project with this command `wrangler generate <my-project-name> https://github.com/cloudflare/worker-typescript-template`.

When I generate the OAuth from my Twitter Developer account I checked OAuth v1 and v2 and for my callback URL I gave `http://127.0.0.1:8787` (my local running instance). In the src directory of my project I have 3 files `handler.ts`, `twitterClient.ts`, and `index.ts`. The following are the files' contents:

twitterClient.ts

```
import { TwitterApi } from 'twitter-api-v2'

const client = new TwitterApi ({
    appKey: "<MY APP KEY>",
    appSecret: "<MY APP SECRET>",
    accessToken: "<MY ACCESS TOKEN>",
    accessSecret: "<MY ACCESS SECRET>",
});

export const rwClient = client.readWrite
```

handler.ts

```
export async function handleRequest(request: Request): Promise<Response> {
  return new Response(`Hello worker! this is a ${request.method} request`, {
    headers: { 'content-type': 'text/plain' },
  });
}
```

index.ts

```
import { handleRequest } from './handler'
import { rwClient } from './twitterClient'

const tweet = async () => {
  try {
    await rwClient.v1.tweet('I Tweeted this via an API call')
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
  return new Response('Hello worker!')
}


addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(tweet())
})
```

In addition to the actual app's code above, below are the configuration files of the app.

wrangler.toml

```
name = "<MY APP NAME>"
type = "webpack"
webpack_config = "webpack.config.js"
zone_id = ""
account_id = "<MY ACCOUNT ID>"
route = ""
workers_dev = true
compatibility_date = "2022-04-22"

[build]
command = "npm install && npm run build"
[build.upload]
format = "service-worker"
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'worker.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          // transpileOnly is useful to skip typescript checks occasionally:
          // transpileOnly: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

I run my local cloudflare wrangler instance like this `wrangler dev`, and I get this in my terminal.

```
<myusername>@<mycomputername> <myappdirectory> % wrangler dev
  Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8787
  Detected changes...
  Ignoring stale first change
```

I then use Postman and just do a blank get request to `http://127.0.0.1:8787` and this is what I get in my terminal:

```
<myusername>@<mycomputername> <myappdirectory> % wrangler dev
  Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8787
  Detected changes...
  Ignoring stale first change
{unknown error}
[2022-04-22 16:45:09] GET <APP NAME>.<USER NAME>.workers.dev/ HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Notice the `{unknown error}` I get in my output. I believe this is from the line `console.error(e)` in `const tweet` in the file `index.ts`

So finally... What's the problem? Why won't the my API call cause my Twitter account to tweet "I Tweeted this via an API call"? Also how can I get a clear error message?

One more minor question. Is it unsafe to have a callback url over "http" instead of "https"? Could someone listen to my API call and extract my API credentials?